# bash and expect interaction

Tags: bash, expect

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bash commands go here

/usr/bin/expect - << EndMark
This is the expect script
expect commands go here
and here
until:
EndMark

# More bash commands go here.

exit 0
```

Something like this will allow me to start an expect script from within bash. However when it gets to the More bash commands part, it will stop the expect process (and the processes it spawned)  Is it possible to get back into the same expect script?

```
eg - Start expect script
   - At a certain point leave the expect to bash operations
   - return to the same expect script?
```

Comment: do you want to keep running the expect script as another process while executing the bash commands, or do you want it to stop until you get finished with the bash section?

Comment: i dont think it is applicable because once you get out from expect that's it, if you call it once again it will start from the start

Comment: What I'm doing is changing files in the directory that the expect script is using. The files CANT be there when the script starts, and I can't stop the script to put them in either.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to leave the expect process in order to issue shell commands - you can use the `system` command from within the expect script.